# limitations in SQL used in Snowflake Dashboard Tiles

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are trying to use multi statements in Snowflake Dashboard tiles and do not quite understand the behaviour.

Let's say I create these 2 statements in my tile

```
SET MyVar = ( SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM DEV_CONTROL.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE NOT TABLE_NAME = :Subscription );

SELECT $MyVar;
```

If I highlight the first line and run it, I get a successful statement that does not return anything.
If I get back to my tile, I see "Statement executed successfully."

If I then go back to my SQL statements and highlights both, then run it, I get the name of the first table.
Going back to my dashboard, I now see the result of the second statement, my table name.

I find this both confusing and incoherent...

The data showed in the tile should reflect ALL the code I entered, not just what I happened to highlight and run the last time I looked at the code?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not documented well. As you mentioned, the tiles show only the result of the last executed query - at least this is what I observed on my tests.

Using Snowflake Scripting can be helpful here:

```
DECLARE
    MyVar VARCHAR;
    Rcount NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME INTO :MyVar FROM GOKHAN_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE NOT TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TEST%' ORDER BY random(); 
    SELECT IFNULL(ROW_COUNT,0) INTO :Rcount FROM GOKHAN_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = :MyVar;
    RETURN :MyVar || ' ' || :Rcount;
END;
```

The above code will be executed as a block.